# Would it be in any way possible to bake cookies using a blowtorch?

Tags: baking, cookies, blowtorch

I was wondering, what if it was possible to bake cookies using blowtorches? It would be the ultimate in convenience. I do realise, though, that the surface would sooner char than bake through with a blowtorch, so perhaps its possible to achieve baking or similar results using extremely thin sheets of batter? It would become something like thins...

Suggestions for alternative foods I can try making with this line of thought would be appreciated as well.

Comment: On the contrary, it would not be convenient at all. Standing around waving a blowtorch at food .vs. putting it in a convenient, self-controlled hot box (that's an oven) - no contest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In other culinary applications, blowtorches are used to put a sear on foods that you exactly do not want to cook at the temperature used for searing. For a demonstration, point a blowtorch at any kind of dough that you know would steam leaven if brought to a bulk temperature over a 100°C - the surface will be very visibly burnt quickly long before any steam leavening will happen. Also, you could handle the dough with unprotected hands seconds after applying the blowtorch heat - not advisable with dough that has been heated through in an oven...

Anything containing a lot of sugar will easily burn to a black char if brought to a temperature much above 160°C, as can be seen even with an oven: Bread or pizza doughs, being low sugar low fat, can be cooked in a 250°C oven - however, for pastry rich in sugar and fat, even 180°C means you need to keep a close eye on the oven in order not to get the surface of your baked goods burnt and bitter. Fat also matters because many fats and/or their impurities will also start to chemically change for the worse in that temperature zone, as can be seen with unclarified butter.
Using a blowtorch would mean that you would thoroughly encounter all these negative effects on the surface before getting any significant heat into the mass of your dough.

Answer (score 3):

While pointing a blow torch at cookie dough is 'possible' the direct heat is likely to caramelize the sugars too fast to get anything that resembles a cookie. If you look at The [Science of Cooking](http://www.scienceofcooking.com/blowtorch-cooking.htm) they do offer some ideas but none of them would be consistent with the *idea of baking a cookie.*

There are a variety of [articles and videos](https://www.google.com/search?q=cooking%20with%20a%20blowtorch&oq=cooking%20with%20a%20blow&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.4118j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) online about cooking other things with a blow torch.